# RTL characters in code snippets

Tags: bug, code-formatting, rtl

Here is a code snippet, snapshotted from a character-based terminal that doesn't apply the [Unicode bidi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text#Unicode_bidi_support):

[image]

Here's the same code snippet in Stack Overflow: `{{a|1}} {{א|1}}`

Note how the components of the second term are reversed - the Hebrew aleph character has RTL directionality, which affects the directionality of nearby "weak" characters.

This is intended behavior in normal text but pretty confusing in a code snippet (the actual example is from MediaWiki markup, where `a`/`א` are template names and `1` is a parameter, but most readers will think `1` is the template name and `א` is the parameter in the second template call). Code snippets should be forced to LTR, no matter what characters they use.

The same issue affects the editor as well. There's probably no easy fix for that as there is no way to tell what's code and what's text.

Comment: And how would you propose that would be implemented? [`direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction) doesn't exactly do much there.

Comment: Also, that snippet [looks fine in Google Chrome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdfTM.png), so I don't really understand what the bug is...

Comment: It doesn't look fine. As I said, it's the same snippet, just with `a` replaced by `א`. Paste it in a shell and you'll see. Not sure about the correct fix, maybe wrapping it in `<bdo>`. Or `unicode-bidi: plaintext;` although that would go against the CSS standard's guidance of leaving `unicode-bidi` to DTD authors, but arguably providing CSS for a site with user-generated content is closer to authoring a DTD than authoring a document.

Comment: That's the kind of information that should've been in this bug report from the start...

Comment: I don't think it's the bug reporter's role to suggest solutions. I'm not particularly familar with handling RTL text, those suggestions might have problems I am not aware of.

Comment: Maybe not, but it is your role to explain why something is bad, wrong, confusing or undesirable...

Comment: Tried to clarify the issue.

Comment: That's a lot better!

Comment: not sure... I don't have numbers but I've got a feeling people typing rtl texts even in code blocks would expect it to be rtl. I fear your use case is less common. Fast looking at the right-to-left tag [here is one such case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56907889/css-right-to-left-keyframes-transform-100-to-transform-none) where I feel the user would have been confused if it did work the way you want it to. Maybe this should be a tag specific thing, only for languages where such chars are actual commands?

Comment: In this case, isn't the non-confusing case compliant?

Comment: Looking at my editor's behavior (Visual Studio 2017), it appears to do the Right Thing - not cancel RTL altogether, but somehow change the algorithm so that the `|` is not considered weak.
For reference, I used the fuller test text `{a|1} {אבג|1}`, which VS correctly displays as: Opening curly brace, Gimel, Bet, Alef, pipe, one, closing curely brace.

Comment: @Jonathan interesting, thanks! That does seem like the best solution conceptually. I doubt a website would have that level of fine-grained control, though.

Comment: Visual studio online behaves the same like the native Visual Studio, so it's possible to implement in the web. It appears to implement its own `span` elements, each with  its own `dir`. Presumably, this works hand-in-hand with its syntax highlighting.